# Windows Batch job to precede all lines with filename

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have 50 text files and each text file has around 6000 lines. I am looking to make a batch job that will append the filename to each line of the text file.

I have a batch job to append data to the each line but cant wrap my head around getting the filename

This is what I have so far

```
@echo off
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (input.txt) do (
set /a N+=1
echo ^"(my filename)%%a^",>>output.txt
)
```

--- Example

filename 3315.txt

```
124123541234
1234123
2345623462356234
12341234562356245
```

Desired end result

```
3315124123541234
33151234123
33152345623462356234
331512341234562356245
```

Comment: …unless I'm missing something change`my filename`to`input.txt`

Comment: no i dont want to manually type the file name 50 times.. the filenames will be different everytime.

Comment: you've already typed it into the parentheses, what's the difference? Let me reword... whatever you put in the upper parentheses put in the lower ones too!

Comment: I know that but what i want to acheive is I want the batch job to go through all the 50 files store the filename in the upper bracket and do all the 50 files in 1 go //

Comment: An example might have been helpful...

Comment: http://pastebin.com/6ZwRZXed  i hop this helps

Comment: The solutions using `for /f` do what you need (e.g. Magoo's). However, since you have many large files, you may find that the `for /f` command works very slowly. If you want something quicker, consider using [the GNU utility](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm) `sed`.

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"

FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\R*.txt" '
 ) DO (
 (
  FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%q IN ("%sourcedir%\%%a") DO (
   ECHO (%%a^)%%q
  )
 )>"%destdir%\%%~na.out"
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a filemask of `R*.txt` to restrict the number of files processed on my test system.

Essentially, build a list of filenames using the `dir` command, and assign each to `%%a` in turn.

read each line of `%%a` into `%%q` and output to a new file in the destination directory made up of the name part of `%%a` (`%%~na`) and `.out`

--- later

To prepend the name part of the file to each line of the file, change

```
   ECHO (%%a^)%%q
```

to

```
   ECHO %%~na%%q
```

`%%~na` selects the **N**ame part of `%%a` (see `for /f|more` from the prompt for more info)

Comment: One minor problem with this and similar solutions is that the `for /f` command completely ignores blank lines in the input files.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou: True. Without examples, we can but speculate.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/6ZwRZXed  this is what i want to achevie for 50 files with different name so i have files 3315.txt,5424.txt,1563.txt .... etc and i want to append the first line of all these files with the filename(without extension)